# Ruby scripting: the %x( command ) and unexpected ( errors

Tags: ruby, bash, scripting

I found a tool to find duplicate files, and now I'm ready to delete the duplicates. I stared at the format of the output file for a bit, and came up with this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 

contents = File.open('fdupes-result', 'rb') { |f| f.read }
duplicates = contents.split("\n\n")

duplicates.each do |set|
  list = set.split("\n").reverse
  list.drop(1).each do |filename|
      # print "rm #{filename}"
      %x[ rm #{filename} ]
  end
end
```

The commented `print` statement is what I used to test the thing non-destructively, and it seemed to work great. But when I added the `%x` command I started getting

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I didn't know what was happening, until I realized that the file has names like `/media/LilGalactus/music/Robert Johnson - Complete Recordings/Robert Johnson - The Complete Recordings (Disc2of2)[EAC-FLAC](oan)/s.gif` -- i.e., my data is full of unescaped spaces, brackets, and the like. For about 30 seconds I considered escaping the characters by using vim commands like `:s/\(/\\\(/g` and I think the limitations of that method are pretty obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend that you forget that `%x[...]` (and the backtick equivalent) exists. They're very difficult and messy to use correctly and safely and there are better alternatives.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of escaping them just add double-quotes like this: `%x[ rm "#{filename}" ]`

Comment: Ah HA! So many ways to precisely handle data in *nix -- thanks!

Comment: What happens when `filename` is `gotcha mr "I don't need to escape anything"`?

Comment: Yeah, this way you will some day shoot yourself in another foot.

Answer (score 6):

```
File.unlink(filename)
```

`unlink` will be a few magnitudes faster and does not need argument escaping

if you for some reason still want to use shell call - use:

```
system("rm", filename)
```

this way it will escape everything that must be escaped

Comment: +1 for noting the multi-argument version of `system` before I finished mine.